# Removed first word in an excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress, add-filter

Been searching for a way how to remove the first word in an excerpt generated by wordpress. Somehow all possible solutions online didn't work.

I have a custom post type archive page where it display all events. I'm using Visual Composer to create the event. So basically the text i'd like to remove is the heading.

I have this code below but it's not working as it should.

I get the idea from this [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/215937/trim-first-2-words-of-the-exceprt) and tried the solutions there which i'm no a bit closer to what i wanted.

```
add_filter( 'wp_trim_excerpt', function ( $text )
{
// Make sure we have a text
if ( !$text )
    return $text;

$text               = ltrim( $text );
$text_as_array      = explode( ' ', $text );

// Make sure we have at least X amount of words as an array
if ( 10 > count( $text_as_array ) )
    return $text;

$text_array_to_keep = array_slice( $text_as_array, 2 );
$text_as_string     = implode( ' ', $text_array_to_keep );
$text               = $text_as_string;

return $text;
}):
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do something simple like this:

```
function removeFirstWord($text)
{
    return substr($text, strpos($text, " ") + 1);
}
```

This simply returns everything after the first space.  You can also add a trim function on there to ensure the first character isn't a space.

Comment: Thanks @EatPeanutButter but your code didn't work. The text is still there.

Comment: Edit your question and post exactly what your code looks like, what inputs you're using, and what the output looks like.

Comment: Updated question with the original solution i've used.

Comment: So how does that not work like you expect?  The only thing to fix with the code you posted is that array_slice() uses a zero index, so you should start at 1, not 2. Otherwise, post *actual* inputs and *actual* outputs from this function.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i got it working now.

Here's the final code. Should be inside the loop.

```
$excerpt = get_the_content();
$excerpt = preg_replace("~(?:\[/?)[^/\]]+/?\]~s", '', $excerpt);
$excerpt = wp_trim_words( $excerpt, 30, '...' );    
echo $excerpt;
```